# order by two columns in angular js (average, time seconds)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I'm trying to sort two columns with angular js, column average and another time in seconds, but the seconds not sorted correctly. 
I currently returns this:

[image]

I'm doing something as a ranking.

my html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in ranking | orderBy:['-promedio','tiempo']" >
  <td >{{ user.usuario }}</td>
  <td > {{ user.promedio }} </td>
  <td > {{ user.tiempo}} </td>
</tr>
```

my ctrl:

`EncuestApp.controller('ResultadoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ranking =[
        {
         "id":"5",
        "tiempo":"15.737",
        "promedio":"0.4",
        "usuario":"rfmartinez"
        },
        {
        "id":"6",
        "tiempo":"35.694",
        "promedio":"0.8",
        "usuario":"mm"
        },
        {
        "id":"7",
        "tiempo":"303.328",
        "promedio":"0.8",
        "usuario":"mn"
        },
        {
        "id":"8",
        "tiempo":"40.327",
        "promedio":"0.8",
        "usuario":"mnn"
        }
    ];
});`

which is the best way to solve it?

thanks

Comment: store number as number and not strings in `ranking`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stored all numbers as strings (e.g. `"10.5"` instead of just `10.5`). Therefore AngularJS sorts your entries by the textual representation of the numbers. Change all numbers to actual numbers in your data model:

```
EncuestApp.controller('ResultadoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ranking =[
        {
        "id": 5,
        "tiempo": 15.737,
        "promedio": 0.4,
        "usuario": "rfmartinez"
        },
        {
        "id": 6,
        "tiempo": 35.694,
        "promedio": 0.8,
        "usuario": "mm"
        },
        {
        "id": 7,
        "tiempo": 303.328,
        "promedio": 0.8,
        "usuario": "mn"
        },
        {
        "id": 8,
        "tiempo": 40.327,
        "promedio": 0.8,
        "usuario": "mnn"
        }
    ];
});
```

Comment: thanks, the problem came from the api, this returned value as string me, and I've only used floatval function php to convert float.